# Pointer Variable and String copying - C

Tags: c, string, pointers

So I'm cruising through Learn C the Hard Way (just enrichment) - but one bonus problem I've come across is the following -

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * mystrcpy(char *, char *);

int main(void) {
  char dest[100];
  char src[] = "Test string\n";
  char *p;

  if (p = mystrcpy(dest,src)) {
    printf("%s\n",p);
    return(0);
  }
  else {
    printf("null pointer received\n");
    return(1);
  }
}
/* mystrcpy: Copy a string from s to a buffer pointer to by d. 
   d = destination buffer
   s = source string
   return value = a pointer to the beginning of the string in the
   destination buffer. 
*/
char * mystrcpy(char *d, char *s) {
}
```

I know that *d and *s are both pointer variables, but I'm not exactly sure what that means, nor how to use them in the context of this problem. Any help or "pointers" (no pun intended) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, it is not `*d` and `*s` that are pointer variables, it is `d` and `s`.  The difference is very important.

Comment: Read this documentation on string copy http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy

Comment: In any case, surely your book presents material about pointers and how to use them before offering an exercise such as you describe.  If that material leaves you uncertain about how to approach the exercise then it is probably worth your while to figure out what aspects of the text seem unclear or incomplete, and to ask specifically about those.

Comment: Don't skip lessons!

Comment: Google "c pointer tutorial"

Comment: So after looking at tutorials, etc., I'm honestly still not too sure on implementation of the mystrcpy function. Everything I've tried has either resulted in "T" or "null pointer". I'm kinda lost still.

Answer (score 0):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be adjusted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the call to `mystrcpy`, the *expressions* `src` and `dest` "decay" from type "array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", so what the function actually receives are the pointer values corresponding to the addresses of the first element of each array.

You can access the contents of each array by using the `[]` subscript operator on the pointer expressions<sup>1</sup>:

```
d[i] = s[i];
```

or, you can dereference each pointer directly:

```
*d = *s;
```

and adjust the value of each pointer

```
d++;
s++;
```

Note that these operations may be combined:

```
*d++ = *s++;
```

From there it's just a matter of determining where the source string ends.

---

1. The expression `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)`; given the pointer value `a`, offset `i` elements (*not bytes!*) from that address and dereference the result.  This is why the array conversion rule mentioned above exists in the first place.